# How Does CodeIgniter's Form Validation Library Handle XSS Filtering?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

The CodeIgniter form validation library provides the option to 'prep' data from a form that is being validated. The following is a snippet from the documentation:

> `$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');`

The `xss_clean` parameter at the end supposedly passes the post data through the `xss_clean` function.

I am wondering how do I use the `$_POST` data `username`? Did the `xss_clean` function act directly on the `$_POST` variable so that I may then do: `$username = $this->input->post('username');`, and actually get the filtered data? What if I place that last statement before the validation line? Will `$username` contain unfiltered data in this case? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The validation does xss clean, but it has nothing to do with `$this->input->post('username')`. That line right there will xss clean automatically, completely independent of your validation stuff (assuming you have global xss filtering on). As a matter of fact, I'm willing to bet that doing both will actually xss clean it *twice*, because I'm pretty sure that validation just creates a copy of the array..it doesn't actually modify $_POST.

But as I said, if you're accessing it by `$this->input->post('username')`, it will be cleaned regardless.

Comment: You mentioned `$this->input->post('username') will xss clean automatically`. Doesn't it only xss clean it if you pass TRUE as the second parameter? User Guide says `XSS filter is enabled by setting the second parameter to TRUE` (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

from the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

"If anything disallowed is encountered it is rendered safe by converting the data to character entities"

so yes, after running $this->input->post('username') through the form validation with the xss option set any dirty data will come out clean.

and yes, if you place that statement before the validation line it will not be cleaned.

note that you can run xss globally on all form submitted data so that you don't need to include it in your validation rules.

Comment: so yes, after running $this->input->post('username') through the form validation with the xss option set any dirty data will come out clean.

you have to put a second argument to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking through system/libraries/Input.php You can see exactly how the work is done in there.

I always recommend turning the global xss_clean on. There is very little impact on performance, unless you are *not* checking for xss on some fields, purposely.